# http2 AssertionError: false == true

Tags: node.js, http2

node -v 6.9.2
http2@3.3.6

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error
    AssertionError: false == true
    at Connection._send (/var/www/revizor-game.ru/node_modules/http2/lib/protocol/connection.js:326:9)
    at runCallback (timers.js:637:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:610:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:582:5)
```

My server.js

```
$lib.s = new Hapi.Server();
var listener = http2.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('/var/www/revizor-game.ru.key', 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/var/www/ca.crt', 'utf8'),
    pfx: fs.readFileSync('/var/www/pfx.pfx')
});

$lib.s.connection({
    listener: listener,
    host: 'revizor-game.ru',
    port: 443,
    tls: true
});
```

and boot.js (clustering) - http://pastebin.com/YzGsJVUk